# MS Word: Getting the actual ASCII code of an inserted symbol

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a VBA code for MS-Word to remove rows with the unticked symbol from a table.
To do that, I need MS-Word to recognize it and differentiate between it and the ticked symbol. But unlike Excel, MS-Word seems to be bad at it.

To focus on the problem, I inserted the symbols, but I can not get the correct ASCII code of the character I have just inserted.

Here is what I tried:

```
Sub SymbolsTest()
    Selection.InsertSymbol 163, "Wingdings 2", True 'Insert unticked
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1, Extend:=wdExtend 'Select it
    Debug.Print AscW(Selection.Text) & "  " & Selection.Text 'Ask for ASCII
    Selection.Collapse 0
    Selection.InsertSymbol 82, "Wingdings 2", True 'Insert ticked
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1, Extend:=wdExtend 'Select it
    Debug.Print AscW(Selection.Text) & "  " & Selection.Text 'Ask for ASCII
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
40  (
40  (
```

I would expect it to be:

```
163  ?
82  ?
```

I also tried `?Selection.Characters(1) = Selection.Characters(2)` in the immediate window while selecting both of them, and I got `True`

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Symbols to be recognized]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know

- there is no simple way to get the character's code point or font name directly using any of the properties of the Selection or Range
- In this situation, Word always uses the code point 40 (")"), and internally, it does does store the name of the font you specified and a Unicode codepoint (e.g. U+F052 for the checked box).

Two things you can do. If the character is not 40, assume it already has the correct codepoint (although I am not certain about that). But if not,

- retrieve the .XML or .WordOpenXML of the Selection or Range and look for the relevant element, e.g. `><w:sym w:font="Wingdings 2" w:char="F052"/>` in both the old-style .XMLand the newer .WordOpenXML. You could either search for the text `<w:sym` and look for the font and codepoint in the following text, or "do it properly" using an XML parser. In that case, it may be useful to know that `F052` either means "the Unicode character with code point F052, or it means "it's F000 + the code point in the original character set", i.e. Wingdings 2 in this case.

e.g. one way would be to make a reference in the VB Editor's Tools-References to the Microsoft XML library (in this case 6.0) and use code along these lines:

```
Sub getCharFontAndCodepoint()
Dim xdoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xSymNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Set xdoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xdoc.async = False
If xdoc.LoadXML(Selection.XML) Then
  xdoc.SetProperty _
    "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:w='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml'"
  Set xSymNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//w:sym/@w:font")
  If xSymNodes.Length > 0 Then
    Debug.Print xSymNodes(0).NodeValue
  End If
  Set xSymNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//w:sym/@w:char")
  If xSymNodes.Length > 0 Then
    Debug.Print xSymNodes(0).NodeValue
  End If
End If
Set xSymNodes = Nothing
Set xdoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

- or, if you only need the codepoint, copy the character and use paste special to paste it using the `Unformatted Unicode Text` format, e.g.

  ```
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.PasteSpecial link:=False, DataType:=22 ' There does not seem to be a named enum for this particular format
   Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=WdMovementType.wdExtend
   Debug.Print Hex(AscW(Selection))
   Selection.Document.Undo
  ```