# Can't get exact symbol converting / symbol from word to xml in C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word libary

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, ms-word

I have program that converts Microsoft Word file to xml file. But when Word file consists of symbols which are inserted from insert -> symbol window with font type "Symbol" program can not convert it properly. So instead of getting the proper symbol I get "(" symbol for each of them. Even when I try to paste those symbols here it appears such way: •• 
We use Winwordcontrol.document.application.selection.range for selecting lines. This class has Text, First or etc methods. It returns me selected lines as a string. When program tries to convert selected lines to xml it returns "(" instead of inserted symbols of Word. The rest of lines are converted properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xhDL.png)

I tried to get Unicode of these symbols, but it returned me Unicode of the "(" symbol.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `/` character in the Symbol font pretends to have decimal code point 164 (0xA4), [which it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface)#Encoding), but Word saves it differently, namely:

```
<w:sym w:font="Symbol" w:char="F0A4"/>
```

See also [MS Word: Getting the actual ASCII code of an inserted symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591555/ms-word-getting-the-actual-ascii-code-of-an-inserted-symbol). It also gets copied as such, being a Unicode character in the [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) (starting with F0 and all).

Naive solutions, as I don't know the proper way to get those characters back from the XML:

1. Don't use Symbol or other fonts to represent symbols; Unicode can contain them all.
2. In your code, map the F0-characters back to their Unicode equivalent using a custom mapping function, then replace them in the string you receive from Word.

An implementation of #2:

```
var input = "Test Math ";

var output = input.Replace("\uF0C1", "\u2287");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Outputs:

> Test Math ⊇